# Linq projecting to a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class MarketViewModel
{
    public MarketViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string Item { get; set; }
    public List<SubItem> StationName { get; set; }

}

public class SubItem
{
    public string Item { get; set; }
}

var active = from actives in activeStations
    group actives.StationName by new { actives.Market,actives.StationGroupInt } into g
    select new MarketViewModel { Item = g.Key.Market, StationName = g.tolist() };
```

In the above LINQ code, my question is how do I project to `MarketviewModel`, as you see stationname is a list of subItem.

**StationName = g.tolist()**

( how do I re-write this piece ?) so that it creates a list of subitem objects

**EDIT**

activestations entity contains

- stationName(string),
- stationgroupInt (int),
- market (string)

---

```
market stationName StationgroupInt
----------------------------------

A       B              1
A       C              1
A       D              1
```

Comment: You already are projecting to that type.

Comment: What is the type in `activeStations`. You need to provide some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Select` on group `g` to create the sub item.

```
var active = from actives in activeStations
             group actives.StationName by new { actives.Market,actives.StationGroupInt } into g
             select new MarketViewModel { 
                 Item = g.Key.Market, 
                 StationName = g.Select(stationName => new SubItem { 
                     Item = stationName 
                 }).Tolist() 
             };
```

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: @user1005310 If answer is useful you can also vote up.